# Convert decimal to binary (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, binary, decimal

I have to write a function recursively to convert a given decimal string ad return a binary. I can't change the first 3 lines of the function(n = Len(a) ... return str(bin(int(a)))) and I don't understand why my solution doesn't work. Does anyone have any suggestions?

{str} -> {str}

```
def converttobin(a: str) -> str:
    n = len(a)
    if n == 1:
        return str(bin(int(a)))
    else:
        return converttobin(str(int(a) % 2)) + str(int(a) % 2)
```

Comment: Such an approach needs to separate quotient from remainder – that is ``//`` and ``%``. Your code only ever computes the remainder ``%``.

Comment: Please do not trash questions like this. The task, code, restrictions and even language tag were totally different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Decimal to Binary Recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768228/python-decimal-to-binary-recursive)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending the remainder, send the quotient `str((int)a//2)` to the function call.

For decimal to binary conversion, we take remainders as the current output and further apply the conversion on the quotient.